# dcc32 Warning UnloadProcs.pas(59): W1035 Return value of function 'GetType' might be undefined

Tags: delphi, function, build, warnings, delphi-xe2

There is a data type

```
type
TDataTypeId = (DataTypeId_String, DataTypeId_SmallInt, DataTypeId_Integer, DataTypeId_Word,
               DataTypeId_Boolean, DataTypeId_Float, DataTypeId_Currency,
               DataTypeId_BCD, DataTypeId_FmtBCD, DataTypeId_Date,
               DataTypeId_Time, DataTypeId_DateTime, DataTypeId_TimeStamp,
               DataTypeId_Bytes, DataTypeId_VarBytes, DataTypeId_Blob,
               DataTypeId_Memo, DataTypeId_Graphic, DataTypeId_fmtMemo,
               DataTypeId_FixedChar, DataTypeId_WideChar, DataTypeId_LargeInt,
               DataTypeId_Array, DataTypeId_FixedWideChar, DataTypeId_WideMemo);
```

There is a function which accepting a line comprising one of values of this type, returns this value

```
Function GetType(str: string): TDataTypeId;
var
typeidx: TDataTypeId;
typestr: string;
begin
for typeidx := Low(TDataTypeID) to High(TDataTypeID) do
 begin
  typestr:=GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TDataTypeId),Ord(typeidx));
  typestr:=Copy(typestr, 12, length(typestr)-11);
  //Memo.Lines.Add(typestr+'\n');
  if (AnsiCompareStr(str, typestr)=0) then
     Result:=typeidx
 end;
 end;
```

As a result, there is an assembly

```
[dcc32 Warning] UnloadProcs.pas(59): W1035 Return value of function 'GetType' might be undefined
```

How to transform function that warning didn't arise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler warning is accurate. If the if statement never evaluates to `True`, because no match was found, then the loop does not assign to Result. And then the function exits without assigning a value.

Your options:

1. Assign a value to `Result`, after the loop completes, that indicates that no match was found.
2. Raise an exception, after the loop completes.

I would also suggest that you `exit` immediately after assigning `Result`. No point continuing round the loop when you have found the answer.

I would likely write this function like this:

```
Function GetType(str: string): TDataTypeId;
var
  typestr: string;
begin
  for Result := low(Result) to high(Result) do
  begin
    typestr := GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TDataTypeId),Ord(typeidx));
    typestr := Copy(typestr, 12, length(typestr)-11);
    if AnsiSameStr(str, typestr) then
      exit;
  end;
  raise EEnumNotFound.CreateFmt('Enum not found: %s', [str]);
end;
```

Note the use of the `Result` variable as the loop variable. This is idiomatic and has the benefit of reducing the number of local variables that you declare.

I agree that you could probably solve your problem more effectively using `GetEnumValue`, but I wanted to show you how to deal with the compiler warning in an idiomatic fashion.

Answer (score 1):

About the general way of using `result` in such a loop, here is how you may code the function:

```
Function GetType(const str: string): TDataTypeId;
var
typestr: string;
begin
 for result := Low(TDataTypeID) to High(TDataTypeID) do
 begin
  typestr:=GetEnumName(TypeInfo(TDataTypeId),Ord(result));
  typestr:=Copy(typestr, 12, length(typestr)-11);
  //Memo.Lines.Add(typestr+'\n');
  if (AnsiCompareStr(str, typestr)=0) then
     exit; // if found, returns result value
 end;
 result := DataTypeId_String; // returns STRING type by default
end;
```

This is one of the only cases when you can use a loop variable outside the scope of the loop. Code generated is correct, and optimized.

I suppose that you should better define a dedicated `TDataTypeId` item like `DataTypeId_Unknown` or raise an exception if it is not found.

Comment: Regarding using loop variable outside the loop, there's nothing special here. So long as, after the loop ends, you assign to the loop variable, before reading it you are fine. The point is that the loop variable is in an ill-defined state immediately after the loop terminates normally.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I do not agree. The `result` variable is used within the loop as loop iteration index, and is still defined as expected if the loop is quit via the `exit` keyword. In normal loops, the index is undefined when the loop exists, e.g. can be +1 to the last value inside the loop, or even undefined if the loop did not iterate. It is guaranteed by the compiler that a result variable will be defined, whereas you do not have any guarantee of the loop value if there is an `exit` within its process. IMHO there is *something special* here.

Comment: My remark about using `result` in the loop is that it is safe to use the loop variable iterator, whereas it is not for "normal" non-result variables.

Comment: Not so but otherwise. The special Result variable is just as undefined at the end of the loop as is a normal local variable. That's why you have to assign to it after the loop completes. When you break out of the loop the loop iterator is well-defined. It only becomes undefined when the loop terminates normally. Nothing special here.

Answer (score 0):

Others have explained the warning, but the better implementation of the routine would be something like:

```
uses
  TypInfo, ConvUtils;

Function GetType(str: string): TDataTypeId;
var idx: Integer;
begin
  idx := GetEnumValue(TypeInfo(TDataTypeId), 'DataTypeId_'+str);
  if(idx <> -1)then Result := TDataTypeId(idx)
  else RaiseConversionError('Unknown typeID name: '+str);
end;
```

ie no need to loop throught all the enum values and compare them as strings, use the `GetEnumValue` function instead.